# How do I put adjacent lines in a .txt file on the same line in linux bash?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, printf, echo

so I am new to bash linux and I am trying to fix a .txt file.

I have a .txt file that looks something like this:

```
blueberry, "yummy", 12345, "I love fruit and eating apples"
blueberry, "tasty", 4455, "fruit is good for you"
blueberry, "yum", 109833, "I go crazy for fruit"
blueberry, "wooohh", 1347672, "I love fruit and 
eating apples"
blueberry, "yummy yummy", 1023433, "I love fruit more than my dog"
blueberry, "yummy", 12345, "I love fruit and eating apples"
blueberry, "something good to eat", 42, "fruit is the 
greatest thing EVER"
blueberry, "tasty", 4455, "fruit is good for you"
blueberry, "yum", 109833, "I go crazy for fruit"
```

I want to create a new .txt file that looks like this:

```
blueberry, "yummy", 12345, "I love fruit and eating apples"
blueberry, "tasty", 4455, "fruit is good for you"
blueberry, "yum", 109833, "I go crazy for fruit"
blueberry, "wooohh", 1347672, "I love fruit and eating apples"
blueberry, "yummy yummy", 1023433, "I love fruit more than my dog"
blueberry, "yummy", 12345, "I love fruit and eating apples"
blueberry, "something good to eat", 42, "fruit is the greatest thing EVER"
blueberry, "tasty", 4455, "fruit is good for you"
blueberry, "yum", 109833, "I go crazy for fruit"
```

(so the random sentences that are on two lines are put back together)

So far I have tried using echo like so:

```
while read p; do                      #for every line in the .txt file
  if[[ $p == "blueberry"* ]]          #if the line starts with 'blueberry' 
       echo -n "$p" >> newfruit.txt   #add the line to newfruit.txt without a new line
  else
       echo " $p" >> newfruit.txt     #add to the current line
  fi
done <fruit.txt
```

but it just returns the exact same .txt file 
I have also tried using printf and echo -e with the same result

any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have several syntax errors: `if[[` needs a space, `if` needs a then. Aside from that, your logic is a little bit incorrect. This should do it:

```
while read p; do
  if [[ $p == "blueberry"* ]]; then
    if [[ -n "$notfirst" ]]; then      # in all blueberry lines but the first,
      echo >> newfruit.txt             # make sure the previous line is terminated
    fi
    echo -n "$p" >> newfruit.txt       # then wait for possible continuation
  else
    echo -n " $p" >> newfruit.txt      # there's the continuation!
  fi
  notfirst=1                           # don't add newline before the first line
done < fruit.txt

if [[ -n "$notfirst" ]]; then          # do add the newline after the last line
  echo >> newfruit.txt
fi
```

Comment: Strongly suggest switching from `echo` to `printf` (either `printf '%s\n'` to emit with a newline, or `printf %s` to emit contents without). See APPLICATION USAGE section of the POSIX echo spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html -- relying on `echo -n` is nonportable.

Comment: Also, putting `>> newfruit.txt` on every line that emits output is reopening the file every time you want to write to it -- wildly inefficient. Just put one `> newfruit.txt` on the outside of the `while` loop.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Agreed on all points; I was going for minimal changes to the original code in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{printf $0}/"$/{printf "\n"}' fruit.txt
```

Print each line without new line character.
If line ends with ", print newline character